No Data in Elastic APM from .NET Core App Using OpenTelemetry OTLP Export
I am integrating OpenTelemetry(1.8.1) with Elastic APM(8.13.4) in my .NET Core(3.1) application. I configured OTLP export and pointed it to Elastic APM. The logs show a status code 200, indicating success, but no data appears in the APM section of Kibana.
Despite these settings, the APM data is not visible in Kibana. Any insights on what might be missing or misconfigured?
Here is the code I used for the integration:
public static IServiceCollection AddOtel(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var resource = GetResourceBuilder();

    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithMetrics(configureMetrics => ConfigureMetrics(configureMetrics, resource))
        .WithTracing(configureTracing => ConfigureTracing(configureTracing, resource));

    return services;
}

private static void ConfigureMetrics(MeterProviderBuilder meterProviderBuilder, ResourceBuilder resource)
{
    meterProviderBuilder
        .SetResourceBuilder(resource)
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(opt =>
        {
            ConfigureOtlpExporter(opt);
        })
        .AddConsoleExporter();
}

private static void ConfigureTracing(TracerProviderBuilder tracerProviderBuilder, ResourceBuilder resource)
{
    tracerProviderBuilder
        .SetResourceBuilder(resource)
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddOtlpExporter(opt =>
        {
            ConfigureOtlpExporter(opt);
        })
        .AddConsoleExporter();
}

private static void ConfigureOtlpExporter(OtlpExporterOptions opt)
{
    opt.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:8200");
    opt.Protocol = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
    opt.ExportProcessorType = OpenTelemetry.ExportProcessorType.Batch;
    opt.BatchExportProcessorOptions = new OpenTelemetry.BatchExportProcessorOptions<Activity>
    {
        MaxQueueSize = 2048,
        ScheduledDelayMilliseconds = 5000,
        ExporterTimeoutMilliseconds = 30000,
        MaxExportBatchSize = 512,
    };
}

private static ResourceBuilder GetResourceBuilder()
{
    var otelAttributes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("host.hostname", Environment.MachineName.ToLowerInvariant()),
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("host.name", Environment.MachineName.ToLowerInvariant()),
        new KeyValuePair<string, object>("deployment.environment", "dev")
    };

    return ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
        .AddService("Product-Service", serviceVersion: "1.0.0")
        .AddAttributes(otelAttributes)
        .AddTelemetrySdk();
}

When I run the application, the console output indicates successful metrics collection:
Metric Name: http.client.request.duration, Duration of HTTP client requests., Unit: s, Meter: OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http/1.0.0.0
(2024-05-20T11:52:39.4382155Z, 2024-05-20T11:55:59.4090200Z] http.request.method: POST http.response.status_code: 200 network.protocol.version: 1.1 server.address: localhost server.port: 8200 url.scheme: http Histogram
Value: Sum: 8.329284399999999 Count: 4 Min: 2.0375531 Max: 2.1776207

It shows a status code of 200, indicating success, but when I check Kibana, no data is visible in the APM section.
What might be missing or misconfigured? Any help would be appreciated!
What I Tried
I configured OpenTelemetry(1.8.1) in my .NET Core(3.1) application as follows:
Added OpenTelemetry for metrics and tracing.
Configured OTLP exporter to send data to Elastic APM(8.13.4) at http://localhost:8200.
Verified in the console logs that data was being exported successfully with status code 200.
What I Expected
I expected the telemetry data (metrics and traces) to appear in the APM section of Kibana, allowing me to monitor my application.
What Actually Happened
Despite the successful status code 200 in the logs, no data is visible in Kibana's APM section.

Please, let me know if you're able to solve this issue. I'm getting the same issue but not able to solve it.
